# How I get the HTTP responses from bash script with curl command?

Tags: linux, bash, http, curl, sh

I have the following command that I execute from the shell:

```
curl -v -s -X GET -H "UserName: myUsername" -H "Password: myPassword" 
https://example.com
```

and from terminal I have the HTTP/1.1 200 response with different response parameters:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 23 Oct 2015 10:04:02 GMT
Name: myName
Age: myAge

...
```

Now, in my .sh file i want take name and age so have the values in my variables $name and $age.
My initial idea was to redirect stdout to a file to parse:

```
curl -v -s -X GET -H "UserName: myUsername" -H "Password: myPassword"
https://example.com > out.txt
```

but the file is empty.

Some ideas to have a variables in bash script enhanced by the HTTP response?

**EDIT: the variables that I want to take are in the header of the response**

Thanks

Comment: add ` -o - ` to redirect the output of curl to stdout, and use backticks to fill a variable from the output of a command.

Answer (score 7):

You have to add `--write-out '%{http_code}'` to the command line and curl will print the HTTP_CODE to stdout.

e.g.`curl --silent --show-error --head http://some.url.com  --user user:passwd --write-out '%{http_code}'`

However I don't know all the other "variables" you can print out.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the grep and cut command to get what you want.

```
response=$(curl -i http://yourwebsite.com/xxx.php -H ... 2>/dev/null)
name=$(echo "$response" | grep Name | cut -d ':' -f2)
age=$(echo "$response" | grep MyAge | cut -d ':' -f2)
```

I changed *Age* to *MyAge* : Age is a standard HTTP header and it is not a good idea to risk to overwrite it.

Answer (score 2):

I resolved:

```
header=$(curl -v -I -s -X GET -H "UserName: myUserName" -H "Password: 
myPassword" https://example.com)

name=`echo "$header" | grep name`
name=`echo ${name:4}`
age=`echo "$header" | grep age`
age=`echo ${age:3}`
```

Comment: This looks like an Awk script wants to be born through pain and agony.